# VACUUM INTO an in-memory database

Tags: sqlite, go

I'm trying to load a sqlite file in memory.

I use "VACUUM INTO" like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58932207), but my in-memory database remains empty.

I don't know what's wrong. :

```
diskDbPath := `file:C:\test.db`
memDbPath := "file:memdb?mode=memory&cache=shared"

diskDb, _ := sql.Open("sqlite3", diskDbPath)

rowcount := 0
diskDb.QueryRow("SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table'").Scan(&rowcount)
fmt.Println("disk db:", rowcount, "tables")

memDb, _ := sql.Open("sqlite3", memDbPath)

_, err := diskDb.Exec("VACUUM INTO '" + memDbPath + "'; ")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

memDb.QueryRow("SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table'").Scan(&rowcount)
fmt.Println("mem db:", rowcount, "tables")

/*
output :
disk db: 9 tables
mem db: 0 tables
*/
```

driver : github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3 v1.14.7, go version : go1.16.2 windows/amd64

Answer (score 0):

A few tries later...
It seems to work if you ping the memory base before the vacuum.
I guess the in-memory db is not really initialized without a first contact.

```
diskDbPath := `file:C:\test.db`
memDbPath := "file:memdb?mode=memory&cache=shared"

diskDb, _ := sql.Open("sqlite3", diskDbPath)

rowcount := 0
diskDb.QueryRow("SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table'").Scan(&rowcount)
fmt.Println("disk db:", rowcount, "tables")

memDb, _ := sql.Open("sqlite3", memDbPath)
memDb.Ping() // <

_, err := diskDb.Exec("VACUUM INTO '" + memDbPath + "'; ")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

memDb.QueryRow("SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table'").Scan(&rowcount)
fmt.Println("mem db:", rowcount, "tables")

/*
output :
disk db: 9 tables
mem db: 9 tables
*/
```